# How to find and change a variable's value through input

Tags: python

I'm trying to make like an ON/OFF switch. Once a variable name is entered I want it going from 'off' to 'on'. There's a lot of variables so code looks really messy if I type '*varx = 'on'*' for every input

```
VAR1 = 'off'
VAR2 = 'off'
VAR3 = 'off'

while True:
    findvar = input('Which variable do you want to turn on?: )
    >> finds the variable and changes value to 'on'
```

I'm trying to get it so when I type ****var1**** on the input, VAR1 goes from '*off*' to '*on*'

I tried dictionary but I haven't found to use dictionary to change variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary.

```
d = {
    'VAR1': 'off',
    'VAR2': 'off',
}

name = input('What variable do you want to turn on? ')
d[name] = 'on'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

```
>>> tel = {'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139}
>>> tel['guido'] = 4127
>>> tel
{'jack': 4098, 'sape': 4139, 'guido': 4127}
```

so you can just use:

```
myvars = {'jack': False, 'sape': False}
myvars[findvar] = not myvars[findvar]
```

And you can adapt this code to your specific variable names and situation.

Comment: And if you really want to have 'on' and 'off' instead of True and False, you can always write a 2nd dict: conv={True: 'on', 'on': True, False: 'off', 'off': False} and use `myvars[findvar] = conv[not conv[myvars[findvar]]]`